# Why do the weights of my iterative reweighted least square algorithm for logistic regression always end up with NaN?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, machine-learning, computer-vision

I'm trying to code a iterative reweighted least square algorithm for logistic regression for face recognition (images represented as a 19x19 greyscale image) but the weights always end up with NaN.

```
w_new = zeros(361,1);

for i = 1:35 % 100-fold cross-validation of 3480 samples

    [ phi, t, ~, ~ ] = removeRows100FoldCV(i, trainx, traint);
    t( t == -1 ) = 0;
    while(true)

        w_old = w_new;
        y = computeYs(w_old, phi);
        R = generateR(y);
        w_new = w_old - inv(phi' * R * phi) * phi' * (y - t);

        if onlyMarginalChangesInW(w_new, w_old) == true
            break;
        end

    end
end
```

The target vector t is originally 1 or -1 depending of the image representing a face or not.

Computation of y:

```
function [ y ] = computeYs( w, phi )

y = zeros(size(phi,1), 1);

for i = 1:size(phi,1)
    a = w' * phi(i,:)';
    y(i) = 1/(1+exp(-a));
end

end
```

Generation of R:

```
function [ R ] = generateR( y )

R = zeros(size(y));

for i = 1:size(R,1)
    R(i,i) = y(i) * (1 - y(i));
end

end
```

And the break condition trigger:

```
function [ result ] = onlyMarginalChangesInW( w_new, w_old )

result = true;
for i = 1:size(w_new)
    if (w_new(i) / w_old(i) > 0.01)
        result = false;
        break;
    end
end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

The `NaN` result occurs in your `inv(phi' * R * phi)`. Did you check your `phi`? Try `cond(phi)` to check whether it is very large. That may cause that inverse operation provides a huge elements.

By the way, I am trying to understand why it is not `w_new = w_old - inv(phi' * R * phi) * phi' * R * (y - t);` in your iterative reweighted least square algorithm implementation?